# OnKeyListener stops working after soft keyboard is hidden

Tags: android, android-fragments, keyboard

On a Fragment, I have the following OnKeyListener. I use it to hide a View internal to that Fragment if its currently shown. If it is not shown, I don't consume the key press and Android does.

```
    getView().setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)) {
                if (isSomeViewShowing) {
                    hideSomeView();
                    return true;
                }
                // Back pressed but view is not showing. Not consuming the event.
                return false;
            }
            // Back not pressed. Not consuming the event.
            return false;
        }
    });
```

It works well to hide the view and getting into the normal Fragment/Activity backstack when the view is not there, but it stops working if the user uses the soft keyboard to input text in an EditText and then hides the keyboard.

I know that the OnKeyListener doesn't work for soft keyboards, and that is OK for my needs. I just need the Listener to continue working after the input has finished and the keyboard is hidden.

Is there a way to prevent this to happen?

A workaround would be to [listen for when keyboard is dismissed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4737265/3128369) and add the OnKeyListener again when the keyboard is dismissed, but implementing this adds too much complexity for a simple task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could override `onBackPressed()` in the `activity` which is using the `fragment` and them send a message to the `fragment` to know that key back was pressed. Something like this:

**Activity:**

```
/**
 * Triggered when the user press back button
*/
@Override
public void onBackPressed(){

    mYourFragment.onBackPressed();

}
```

**Fragment:**

```
public void onBackPressed(){

    if (isSomeViewShowing) {
        hideSomeView();
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you. I have done this on other Fragments, but I don't like that they can't be implemented without changes on the Activity. I will do this anyway since it seems to be the only solution that really solves the problem.